# Numpy array - Replace array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array `a` of shape [300, 3, 3], I like to change this array - `[0.7, 0.3, 0.1]` to `[1, 1, 1]`, if occured in `a`

For example,

Input -

```
b = np.array([[[0.7, 0.3, 0.1], [0.6, 0.4, 0.2], [0.1, 0.2, 0.1]],
             [[0.7, 0.3, 0.1], [0.6, 1.2, 2.1], [1.1, 2.1, 1.1]]
             ])
```

Output-

```
np.array([[[1, 1, 1], [0.6, 0.4, 0.2], [0.1, 0.2, 0.1]],
         [[1, 1, 1], [0.6, 1.2, 2.1], [1.1, 2.1, 1.1]]
         ])
```

How to achieve this in easiest way, without use of looping, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use where method to replace elements of array.

```
b = np.where(b == [0.7, 0.3, 0.1], [1, 1, 1], b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
np.where(b == [0.7, 0.3, 0.1], [1, 1, 1], b)
```